# Сколько VM можно запустить на 1-ом CPU

Tags: виртуализация, виртуальная-машина

Есть сервер с 4 ядерным CPU и 12 гигами оперативки с vmware esxi 5.5 на борту.
Можно ли запустить 6-ть виртуалок в каждой по 3 гига ram и 1-му 1-ядерному cpu?
Будут ли виртуальные машины делить ресурсы между собой? Понимаю что под каждую машину надо выделять четко ядро которое только она будет использовать, четко определенное кол-во оперативки.

Comment: Все зависит от мощности CPU, вы больше упретесь в ОЗУ в данном случае. Хотя смотря что вы ставите на виртуалки... И что за CPU

Comment: Будут ли делить, зависит от того, как вы настроите параметры шаринга ресурсов для каждой виртуалки.

Comment: Эм а можно поподробней если не затруднит, как настроить шаринг?

Comment: Вот скрин на котором видно как распределен шарин ресурсов CPU на моей машине http://clip2net.com/s/3CGKsdJ принцип простой, задается в настройках каждой машины.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Попробую у себя.

Answer (score 1):

Будут. vmware вообще очень хорошо делит ресурсы между гостевыми ОС.
У меня есть хост, на котором (при 4 CPU и 24 ядрах) работает около 30 гостей с 2-4 vCPU каждая. Утилизация на этих гостях копеечная, единицы процентов - работают нормально, отзывчивость высокая.  Типичная многозадачность как она есть.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за информацию.